# Hex To Text python

Tags: python, utf-8, hex

все кодировки перебрал уже :

```
text = '0500031F0202DE0200200418044004380448043A0430002004320020043C043E04380445002004410430043F043E043304300445002004430448043B0435043F0430043B0430D83DDE02'
print(bytes.fromhex(text).decode('utf-8'))
```

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 6: invalid continuation byte
```

ну и т.д , или ошибки или кракозябры

вот здесь распознает более менее , но первые символы сломаны, https://crypt-online.ru/en/crypts/text2hex/, как это побороть? гуглю ничего не получается, кто знает ?

Comment: `.decode('utf-8', 'replace')`

Comment: Судя по куче байт с кодом меньше 0x20 - это скорее всего вообще бинарные данные, а не текст в какой-то кодировке, так что довольно бессмысленно это декодировать как текст

Comment: понятно что это hex, заголовок темы посмотрите, его нужно сначала в бинарные данные перевести, а потом уже в текст декодировать,
Проблема вероятно в том, что сам текс изначально был из разных кодировок кодирован в бинарные, а потом уже в Hex. Придумал костыль  - отсекаем символы до тех пор пока кодировка начинает распозноваться :

Comment: ``` def tryFind(text):
    length  = len(text)
    new  = text
    for i in range(length):
        # print(text[i:])
        try:
            new = bytes.fromhex(text[i:]).decode('utf-16-be')
        except:
            # print("не получилось")
            pass
        if new != text:
            return new

    return(new) ```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '0500031F0202DE0200200418044004380448043A0430002004320020043C043E04380445002004410430043F043E043304300445002004430448043B0435043F0430043B0430D83DDE02'
res=''
for i in range(4,len(text),4):
    print(chr(int(text[i-4:i],16)),end='')
```

Ԁ̟Ȃ� Иришка в моих сапогах ушлепала�

Вы это хотели или убрать не читаемое, или чтобы смайлик был?

Comment: странно , у меня
   print(chr(int(text[i - 4:i], 16)), end='')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ude02' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
я бы хотел бы найти метод, что бы нечитаемые символы отсекал бы воовсе, смайлик в конце вообще читается, а вот эти символы Ԁ̟Ȃ� - вообще непонятно что, может их просто отсекать. решение выше у меня - именно уменьшаю текст слева до тех пор пока он начинает распознаваться, подозреваю что цикл это дороговастенькое решение, может есть проще?